# Error when deploying Django on vercel, Build Failed Command "./build_files.sh" exited with 127

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, vercel

I need to deploy DRF on vercel, and get this error

Build Failed
Command "./build_files.sh" exited with 127

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
      /bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
      /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-idnmrrqg/mysqlclient_b22b8ce7df8348dab3542acc3f2a7a45/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
          metadata, options = get_config()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-idnmrrqg/mysqlclient_b22b8ce7df8348dab3542acc3f2a7a45/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
          libs = mysql_config("libs")
        File "/tmp/pip-install-idnmrrqg/mysqlclient_b22b8ce7df8348dab3542acc3f2a7a45/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
          raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
      OSError: mysql_config not found
      mysql_config --version
      mariadb_config --version
      mysql_config --libs
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
× Encountered error while generating package metadata.


./build_files.sh: line 2: python3.10: command not found
Error: Command "./build_files.sh" exited with 127

Deployment completed

BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_127: Command "./build_files.sh" exited with 127
```

I used Python 3.10.7 and MySQL database

vercel.json file:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "shopwise/wsgi.py",
      "use": "@vercel/python",
      "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb", "runtime": "python3.10.7" }
    },
    {
      "src": "build_files.sh",
      "use": "@vercel/static-build",
      "config": {
        "distDir": "staticfiles"
      }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/static/(.*)",
      "dest": "/static/$1"
    },
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "shopwise/wsgi.py"
    }
  ]
}
```

build_files.sh  file:

pip install -r requirements.txt

python3.10 manage.py collectstatic --noinput

How solve the error to get a successful deployment?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a similar architecture. The difference is that I'm using postgres.
In this case of error 127, vercel does not recognize the python3.10 command. I completely removed the commands from build_files and vercel was able to recover the dependencies from requirements.txt, but I couldn't finish the deploy because my project exceeded the 250mb limit of vercel hobby. hope it helps you finding a solution. If i manged to publish, i will update my answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).